# Unknown action No action responded to delete. Actions: add, edit, and index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I am on the index page and click on the delete link to destroy the post i get that error:

```
Unknown action

No action responded to delete. Actions: add, edit, and index
```

The edit link next to delete works with out a problem I do not understand why delete won't work. This is what is in my controller car_controller.rb

```
def delete
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])
    flash[:notice] = "Question #{@car.name} deleted!"
    @car.destroy
    redirect_to :controller => :car, :action => :index
  end

map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
  map.root :controller => "main"
  map.root :controller => "car"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't the action for delete actually destroy?

If you look at a controller that was generated as part of scaffold, you should see what the delete action maps to...

Rails provides the 7 classical RESTful actions out of the box when you generate the controller and each one has the actual URL + method commented above the action method...

```
# DELETE /subject_families/1
# DELETE /subject_families/1.xml
def destroy
  ...
end
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: changing to to 'destroy' does not make a difference it still the same error regarding 'delete'

Comment: also am I right that nothing has to be present in the view for delete.html.erb? or am I missing something @jaydel

Comment: what is the url on the link for delete? I don't know about your question immediately above though, sorry...

Comment: shouldn't that be 'localhost:3000/cars/1/delete' ? I'm out in the weeds guessing at this point but the general member route url has the id before the action and after the controller name.

Comment: Here's a good link to a very concise explanation of collection and member routing: http://railsnotes.com/5-collection-member-methods-within-a-route/

Comment: how would i got about changing the url only for this action, if i change it for other I will lose other functions such as edit which works?

Comment: map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
  map.root :controller => "main"
  map.root :controller => "car"
end

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your request is using the correct HTTP verb. Rails' default for REST resources is to use HTTP DELETE on the destroy action. Are you using GET (a simple link) or POST instead of DELETE?

I recommend checking your routes - run `rake routes` - to confirm what Rails is expecting. If you are using Rails' resources route generator, then I would expect your view template to contain something like this:

```
<%= form_for @car, :html => { :method => :delete } do |f| %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Delete Car' %>
<% end %>
```